# cpp - printing <int> when input is <int><char> (e.g. "1a") using "std::cin << var", when var is of type int. Why?

Tags: c++

```
int var {};
std::cin >> var;
std::cout << var;
```

When I enter a combination of letters and integers (e.g. "13ad", "d4" etc.), I get only the integer part printed.

I get the logic here, but I would expect the program to crash, not to do *this*. I'm guessing it depends on the compiler (G++ in this case). if so - could you direct me to the relevant setting?
or maybe shine some light on this sunject, Thanks.

Comment: It is well documented that when `>>` reads into an `int` it stops immediately as soon as it finds a character that can't be part of an `int`. I strongly recommend approaching C++ with expectations you got from reading [good-quality learning material](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301) as C++ does not reward programming by guesswork very often.

Comment: This has nothing to do with any particular compiler. This is how the language specifies the `>>` operator to work. All compilers (Standard Library implementations, actually) will have the same behaviour.

Comment: Additionally, if you read in the string `"1a"` and convert to an `int` with `std::stoi` you will get `1`.

Comment: Do you think a program that crashes every time the user hits a wrong key would sell many copies?

Comment: Side note: When you do something legitimately wrong in C++, don't count on a crash. More often than not, the program will have tripped over [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and as you can expect from the name, the behaviour of undefined behaviour is undefined. A crash is only one, albeit a common one, possible outcome. Sometimes it will only wound a program and leave it to stagger on and die somewhere innocent and cause you to debug the wrong code or produce bad outputs you don't notice until too late.

Comment: You'll also find that C++ follows an ideology of not making a program pay for anything the programmer didn't ask for. It won't check for an out-of-bounds array access, because making such a check would be a performance penalty for all programs where the programmer didn't screw up. What happens is often left undefined by the C++ Language Standard document. An implementation could perform a bounds check, emit a diagnostic, and start an orderly shutdown, but usually it allows the access to happen, come what may.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. If you wish to validate input contains *only* an integer, you should read in a string and then explicitly test that string with something like the following function.

*An actual integer literal might contain things other than digits, so this is just a basic example.*

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool only_int(std::string s) {
    return std::all_of(
        s.cbegin(), s.cend(),
        [](auto &c) { return std::isdigit(c); }
    );
}
```

Comment: Or use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and use the `pos` parameter to see whether there are any leftover characters.

Comment: Adding to the disclaimer, the code immediately breaks with a negative number.